# Apache Prefixing Path to Virtual Hosts Path

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I've installed fresh install of XAMPP on a Mac. I've set up Virtual Hosts correctly but for some reason when I turn XAMPP on I get an error like so...

> AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot
>   [/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/\xe2\x80\x9c/Users/mac-user/Sites/domain/httpdocs\xe2\x80\x9d]
>   does not exist (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access
>   directory
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/\xe2\x80\x9c/Users/mac-user/Sites/domain/'
>   for error log of vhost defined at
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:34 AH00014:
>   Configuration check failed

Here's my VH config...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@somedomain.com
 DocumentRoot “/Users/mac-user/Sites/domain/httpdocs”
 ServerName khemistry.dev
 ServerAlias khemistry.dev
 ErrorLog “/Users/mac-user/Sites/domain/error”
 CustomLog “/Users/mac-user/Sites/domain/custom” common
 <Directory “/Users/mac-user/Sites/domain/httpdocs”>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What I have noticed is for some reason Apache is prefixing this `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/\xe2\x80\x9c` to the path and I don't know why.

Please help. It's driving me insane.

If you need any more information please ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've actually got two persistent errors in your config, left double quotation marks and right double quotation marks; this is caused by using a word-processing program instead of a plain text editing program to edit your files. Example:

```
“/Users/mac-user/Sites/domain/httpdocs”
```

This should be:

```
"/Users/mac-user/Sites/domain/httpdocs"
```

Your VHost config is full of these - just change them all to plain double quotes and it'll work.

Edit: I've edited the VirtualHost code in your question because it was all on one single line - hopefully it makes it easier to see all of the left-and-right double quotes that need changing to plain double quotes. The below directive (copy-and-paste it) will work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@somedomain.com
 DocumentRoot "/Users/mac-user/Sites/domain/httpdocs"
 ServerName khemistry.dev
 ServerAlias khemistry.dev
 ErrorLog "/Users/mac-user/Sites/domain/error"
 CustomLog "/Users/mac-user/Sites/domain/custom" common
 <Directory "/Users/mac-user/Sites/domain/httpdocs">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It isn't even word processing programs alone: even blog engines like WordPress keep insisting on replacing " in published with “” unless you mark them with code or pre tags. Browsers on the other hand find any double quote when you search for any (i.e. " matches all three). Very irritating, but apparently nowadays beauty trumps accuracy.